# How to bisect a circle to a vertex

Tags: bisect

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want the circle to keep the distance from the outside circle but it has to bisect to the point I marked in the image. in the gif image, it looks like almost same angle but I'm pretty sure both sides are not the same angle. Is there any way to do that?

Thank you

Comment: maybe it's not clear enough to be understood, could you please try again?

Comment: @moonboots I'm sorry that's because of my English. I added an image file. I wanted to position the red hexagon like that so it moves along with 3 lines without messing the inside angle. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the worst case: the small circle skew in all axes, at an arbitrary location, and for the sake of argument, assuming it's not quicker just to create another, centered, small circle.

Pivot set to '3D Cursor', Snap set to 'Vertex' and 'Active'

**To center the small circle to the large one**

- Select all vertices of the large circle
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > Cursor to Selected
- Select all vertices of the small circle
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > Selected to Cursor (Offset)

**To orient the small circle to the large one**

Having centered the small circle, with the 3D cursor also at the center

- Select all vertices of the small circle
- With one of its vertices active, <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>  in turn, snapping the rotations to any of the vertices of the large circle

**To slide the small circle along a bisector of the large one**

Having centered and aligned the small circle

- Select the two vertices at the ends of your bisector of choice.
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to make a Custom Orientation from them, (with 'Use After Creation' checked)
- Select all the vertices of the small circle, and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> move it along your new orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Use Snap To. Remove the diagonal edge **after** you positioned the red hexagon on it.

[image]